# PXE boot to ISO file

Tags: networking, boot, pxe-boot, iso

I have an ISO file for an HP diagnostics boot. Rather than burning a CD for every single computer I want to run diagnostics on, I'm wondering if I could load this file onto a server and allow the computers to PXE boot the interface. I know this is a broad topic, so what information should I look into in order to get it up and running?

Comment: As I see, this Hp Diagnostics thing is an embedded windows. Probably you can hack this, but it probably won't be really simple. In your place I avoid HP if I can in the first line. Secondary, I used the usb version, it is supported by HP and doesn't need hack.

Comment: Its actually very difficult to boot an iso that is limited to extremely specific hardware. This is because most of the times, you won't find anyone else doing it, having a proper documentation and made it online to public use. So you might have to try a lot harder. There are systems that can give you facility to PXE boot an iso like http://www.vercot.com/~serva/ , windows deployment services, clonezilla. I don't think anyone would be able to more than just the name of utilities for PXE boot unless they have done exactly the same as you are trying to do. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

You might succeed by [chainloading](http://ipxe.org/howto/chainloading) iPXE. iPXE seems to support [booting an ISO file from an HTTP server](http://forum.ipxe.org/showthread.php?tid=3728&pid=7616).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MEMDISK](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=MEMDISK).

Example configuration using Syslinux:

```
label killdisk
  menu label KillDisk
  kernel memdisk
  initrd KillDisk.iso
  append iso raw
```